# Installing OpenSUSE 13.2 issues with video

Tags: opensuse

Good afternoon, I'm attempting to install the latest version of OpenSUSE (Tumbleweed) and upon choosing install I lose my video.  I'm currently running with a Nvidia GTX 970.  Unfortunately I don't have the option to use VGA with this card.  Is there a way to get around this so I can proceed through the installation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out.  For those struggling with something similar:

1. boot your pc
2. enter the grub2 config (*press e when system hits grub boot screen*)
3. remove the **"quiet splash"** and replace it with **nomodeset** (*no quotes*)
4. press F10 to boot
5. install should begin

enjoy ;-)